# Условия в vars у Ansible task

Tags: ansible

```
- roles
  - consul
    - vars/main.yml
```

В `main.yml` использую:

```
consul_is_server: {{ true if consul_server is defined else false }}
```

playbook:

```
- hosts: consul-server
  roles:
    - consul
  vars:
    consul_server: true
```

Ошибка:

```
consul_is_server: {{ "true" if consul_server is defined else "false" }}
                            ^
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Сделал так:

```
consul_is_server:  >
    {{ true  if consul_server is defined and consul_server==true else false }}
```

Но тогда `consul_is_server` будет строкой: "False" или "True". 
И тогда в шаблонах приходится кастить в `bool`:

```
"server": {{ "true" if consul_is_server |bool else "false" }}
```

Можно как-то в `vars` написать так проверку условий, чтоб потом в шаблоне кастить не пришлось?

Comment: `"{{ true if consul_server is defined else false }}"` ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin тут только проверка на `defined`, надо, чтоб ещё `true` было

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `ternary`

Документация: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_filters.html

Пример:

```
---
# https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470202/

- name: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470202/
  hosts: test
  vars:
    str1: "asdf1"
    str2: "asdf2"
    cond1: True
    cond2: False
    result1: "{{ cond1 | ternary(str1, str2) }}"
    result2: "{{ cond2 | ternary(str1, str2) }}"
  tasks:
    - name: debug result1
      debug: msg="{{ result1 }}"
      connection: local
    - name: debug result2
      debug: msg="{{ result2 }}"
      connection: local
```

Вывод:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts_debug sample_ru_470202.yml

PLAY [collect info] ************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [myserver1]

TASK [debug result1] ***********************************************************
ok: [myserver1] => {
    "msg": "asdf1"
}

TASK [debug result2] ***********************************************************
ok: [myserver1] => {
    "msg": "asdf2"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
myserver1 : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

PS Более сложный пример вот тут сам спросил сегодня: [Составная переменная в ternary j2-шаблона ansible](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608873/)

Comment: Вообще, я чуток модернизировал вариант от  Nick Volynkin, но за давности лет этот принял :D