# Составная переменная в ternary j2-шаблона ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Небольшой скрипт для сбора информации о серверах в cvs-файл:

```
- name: collect info about servers
  hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - name: template list
      template:
        src="servers_report.j2"
        dest="~/ansible/webservers/servers_report.csv"
      connection: local
```

Простой шаблон servers_report.j2 с фильтром [ternary](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html):

```
hostname;provider;monitoring url;
{% for item in play_hosts %}
{{ item }};{{ hostvars[item].provider }};{{ hostvars[item].monitoring | ternary("https://{{ item }}/monitoring_url/", '') }};
{% endfor %}
```

Список параметров хостов в файле hosts_production (типовой фрагмент):

```
server1 provider="provider1" monitoring=True
server2 provider="provider2" monitoring=False
```

И... не работает: {{ item }} не считается за переменную.

```
hostname;provider;monitoring url; 
server1;provider1;https://{{ item }}/monitoring_url/; 
server2;provider2;;
```

Простые варианты типа `ternary ('1', '2')` [работают без проблем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470202/), вопросы появляются именно в таких случаях посложнее, когда приходится угадывать, как расположить кавычки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для простоты можно считать, что внутри `{{` и `}}` код на Python.

```
{{ hostvars[item].monitoring | ternary('https://'+item+'/monitoring_url/', '') }}
```

`ternary` – функция, в качестве одного из параметров ей нужно передать строку, чтобы получить результирующую строку, сложим строки `'https://'` + item + `'/monitoring_url/'`.